# Chart JS add annotations on line chart to specific labels

Tags: chart.js

I'm looking for something similar to https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-annotation/latest/

But the problem is, that requires you to add the annotations position manually, there seems to be no way to add it together with a label with custom text.

As in match an annotation to a specific label on a line chart.

So on a line chart you might have August 2018, I want an annotation (or label?) on the data point for August 2018 to note something like "Big Event Here".

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: If you want to add data labels, you should try [chartjs-plugin-datalabels](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/)

Comment: I don't want to just add the labels themselves. I want custom annotations to describe a point.

Comment: You should probably still check chartjs-plugin-datalabels. It allows you to fully customize the text of the labels and also select which points have an associated label and which don't; see the section on [formatting](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/formatting.html#formatting)

Comment: As far as I can see though, you need to manually position each label though via x and y, you can't just point it to a data label on the axis.

Comment: No, you don't; you position the labels wrt the points with a rather sophisticated system of anchoring, see [positioning](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/positioning.html#anchoring). Also check their [samples](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/samples/charts/line.html)

Comment: This is the de facto standard for such things in chart.js as chartjs-plugin-annotations is for manually positioned decorations. The only alternative I can think of is to write your own plugin, but that would typically be more complicated.

Comment: You're right, thanks! Now I just need to find a way to add it to one specific label by the name but can't figure that part out.

Comment: To not show a label, your `formatter(value, context)` should return `null` for that data point (that would be the default in your case). To get more info about the current data point the formatter acts for, you should explore the value of the second argument, `context`. In particular `context.dataIndex` and `context.datasetIndex` are usefull, as well as `context.chart`.

Comment: Set up a new one to continue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77928442/chart-js-chartjs-plugin-datalabels-get-dataset-label-and-display-it