# Chart JS chartjs-plugin-datalabels get dataset label and display it

Tags: chart.js

I am currently trying out [chartjs-plugin-datalabels](https://v1_0_0--chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app), and I'm trying to set a label on my line chart to a specific date on the bottom axis.

The [example](https://v1_0_0--chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/positioning.html#visibility) shows how to set the labels for every 2 points, so I have a basic idea where to start. But what I want is a custom label like "Big Event" shown on a specific point where I can match with the dataset label for the axis point name.

So if the axis datapoint label equals "Oct-2018", have a specific label on the chart that notes "Big Event here" for it.

Chart example:

```
var linuxonly = document.getElementById('linuxonly');
    var Chartlinuxonly = new Chart(linuxonly, {
    type: 'line',
    plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
    data: {
    labels: ['Sep-2018','Oct-2018','Nov-2018','Dec-2018','Jan-2019','Feb-2019','Mar-2019','Apr-2019','May-2019','Jun-2019','Jul-2019','Aug-2019','Sep-2019','Oct-2019','Nov-2019','Dec-2019','Jan-2020','Feb-2020','Mar-2020','Apr-2020','May-2020','Jun-2020','Jul-2020','Aug-2020','Sep-2020','Oct-2020','Nov-2020','Dec-2020','Jan-2021','Feb-2021','Mar-2021','Apr-2021','May-2021','Jun-2021','Jul-2021','Aug-2021','Sep-2021','Oct-2021','Nov-2021','Dec-2021','Jan-2022','Feb-2022','Mar-2022','Apr-2022','May-2022','Jun-2022','Jul-2022','Aug-2022','Sep-2022','Oct-2022','Nov-2022','Dec-2022','Jan-2023','Feb-2023','Mar-2023','Apr-2023','May-2023','Jun-2023','Jul-2023','Aug-2023','Sep-2023','Oct-2023','Nov-2023','Dec-2023','Jan-2024'],
    datasets: [
    {
        label: 'Linux',
        lineTension: 0,
        fill: false,
        data: [0.78, 0.72, 0.80, 0.82, 0.82, 0.77, 0.82, 0.81, 0.84, 0.76, 0.79, 0.80, 0.83, 0.83, 0.81, 0.83, 0.90, 0.83, 0.87, 0.89, 0.91, 0.88, 0.86, 0.89, 0.94, 0.90, 0.90, 0.78, 0.91, 0.81, 0.85, 0.85, 0.86, 0.89, 1.00, 1.02, 1.05, 1.13, 1.16, 1.11, 1.06, 1.02, 1.00, 1.14, 1.12, 1.18, 1.23, 1.27, 1.23, 1.28, 1.44, 1.38, 1.38, 1.27, 0.84, 1.32, 1.47, 1.44, 1.96, 1.82, 1.63, 1.39, 1.91, 1.97, 1.95],
        backgroundColor: '#0C7BDC',
        borderColor: '#0C7BDC',
        borderWidth: 1,
       trendlineLinear: {
            style: '#DC267F',
            lineStyle: 'dotted',
            width: 2
        }
    }]
        },
        options: {
            legend: {
                display: true
            },
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
    scales: {
    yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
        beginAtZero:true
        },
                    scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString: 'Percentage of Steam users'
            }
    }]
    },
            tooltips:
            {
                callbacks: {
                    label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
        var value = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
                        var label = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label;
        return label + ' ' + value + '%';
            }
            },
            },
            plugins: {
            datalabels: {
    display: function(context) {
    console.log(context)

}
}
}
    }
    });
```

Comment: Apologies, added the full example chart code as it is right now.

Comment: I see from the option `yAxes` that you are using an older version of chart.js. What is that version and are you bound to keeping it, because the chart works OK in the latest version, except for the y axis options that can easily modified?

Comment: Not really bound to any version no, this is using v2.9.3

Comment: I included a version based on latest chartjs; I haven't included `trendLineLinear`, but I think it should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suspected (in comments), the dates come from the `x` axis, so it's a little bit more complicated to identify the right datapoint
in the datalabels `formatter`. You have to use the second argument, I called it `ctx`:

```js
options: {
    plugins: {
        datalabels: {
            formatter: function(value, ctx) {
                return ctx.chart.data.labels[ctx.dataIndex] === 'Aug-2019' ?
                    'Big Event' : null;
            },
            // other datalabels options.
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a snippet based on your code, adapted to chart.js v4 and with this `formatter` and some other chart.js options. I also made the radius of
the selected point larger so you can see which one it is and decide on anchoring and alignment of the label.

```js
new Chart('linuxonly', {
    type: 'line',
    plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
    data: {
        labels: ['Sep-2018','Oct-2018','Nov-2018','Dec-2018','Jan-2019','Feb-2019','Mar-2019','Apr-2019','May-2019','Jun-2019','Jul-2019','Aug-2019','Sep-2019','Oct-2019','Nov-2019','Dec-2019','Jan-2020','Feb-2020','Mar-2020','Apr-2020','May-2020','Jun-2020','Jul-2020','Aug-2020','Sep-2020','Oct-2020','Nov-2020','Dec-2020','Jan-2021','Feb-2021','Mar-2021','Apr-2021','May-2021','Jun-2021','Jul-2021','Aug-2021','Sep-2021','Oct-2021','Nov-2021','Dec-2021','Jan-2022','Feb-2022','Mar-2022','Apr-2022','May-2022','Jun-2022','Jul-2022','Aug-2022','Sep-2022','Oct-2022','Nov-2022','Dec-2022','Jan-2023','Feb-2023','Mar-2023','Apr-2023','May-2023','Jun-2023','Jul-2023','Aug-2023','Sep-2023','Oct-2023','Nov-2023','Dec-2023','Jan-2024'],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: 'Linux',
                lineTension: 0,
                fill: false,
                data: [0.78, 0.72, 0.80, 0.82, 0.82, 0.77, 0.82, 0.81, 0.84, 0.76, 0.79, 0.80, 0.83, 0.83, 0.81, 0.83, 0.90, 0.83, 0.87, 0.89, 0.91, 0.88, 0.86, 0.89, 0.94, 0.90, 0.90, 0.78, 0.91, 0.81, 0.85, 0.85, 0.86, 0.89, 1.00, 1.02, 1.05, 1.13, 1.16, 1.11, 1.06, 1.02, 1.00, 1.14, 1.12, 1.18, 1.23, 1.27, 1.23, 1.28, 1.44, 1.38, 1.38, 1.27, 0.84, 1.32, 1.47, 1.44, 1.96, 1.82, 1.63, 1.39, 1.91, 1.97, 1.95],
                backgroundColor: '#0C7BDC',
                borderColor: '#0C7BDC',
                borderWidth: 1,
                // trendlineLinear: {
                //     style: '#DC267F',
                //     lineStyle: 'dotted',
                //     width: 2
                // }
            }]
    },
    options: {
        legend: {
            display: true
        },
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        pointRadius: function(ctx){
            return ctx.chart.data.labels[ctx.dataIndex] === 'Aug-2019' ? 8 : 3
        },
        scales: {
            y: {
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                },
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Percentage of Steam users'
                }
            }
        },
        tooltips:
            {
                callbacks: {
                    label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                        var value = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
                        var label = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label;
                        return label + ' ' + value + '%';
                    }
                },
            },
        plugins: {
            datalabels: {
                formatter: function(value, ctx) {
                     return ctx.chart.data.labels[ctx.dataIndex] === 'Aug-2019' ? 'Big Event' : null;
                 },
                font:{
                    size: 20
                },
                align: 'top',
                offset: 10,
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: '#000',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<div style="height: 90vh">
    <canvas id="linuxonly" style="background: rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.5)">
    </canvas>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/2.2.0/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js" integrity="sha512-JPcRR8yFa8mmCsfrw4TNte1ZvF1e3+1SdGMslZvmrzDYxS69J7J49vkFL8u6u8PlPJK+H3voElBtUCzaXj+6ig==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

An alternative solution is to use a custom plugin. This is more complicated than using chartjs-plugin-datalabels but it supports a larger range of styling options.

Here's a sketch of such an approach. I named the plugin `specialLabel` and, it essentially draws on
the canvas in the [`afterDraw`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#rendering) handler, that is, it draws after the other
elements of the chart are completed.

```js
function draw_arrow(ctx, x0, y0, x1, y1) {
    // from https://stackoverflow.com/a/70873674/16466946
    const width = 3;
    const head_len = 9;
    const head_angle = Math.PI / 8;
    const angle = Math.atan2(y1 - y0, x1 - x0);

    /* Adjust the point */
    x1 -= width * Math.cos(angle);
    y1 -= width * Math.sin(angle);
    ctx.lineWidth = 3;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x0, y0);
    ctx.lineTo(x1, y1);
    ctx.stroke();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineTo(x1, y1);
    ctx.lineTo(x1 - head_len * Math.cos(angle - head_angle), y1 - head_len * Math.sin(angle - head_angle));
    ctx.lineTo(x1 - head_len * Math.cos(angle + head_angle), y1 - head_len * Math.sin(angle + head_angle));
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();
}


new Chart('linuxonly', {
    type: 'line',
    plugins: [{
        id: 'specialLabel',
        defaults: {
            offsetX: 30, offsetY: -40,
            textFontSize: 25,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)',
            textColor: '#000',
            lineColor: '#444',
            paddingX: 12, paddingY: 6
        },
        afterDraw(chart, _, pluginOptions){
            const {datasetIndex, xValue, text, offsetX, offsetY, textFontSize,
                backgroundColor, textColor, lineColor, paddingX, paddingY } = pluginOptions;

            const dataIndex = chart.data.labels.indexOf(xValue);
            if(dataIndex < 0){
                return;
            }
            const {x, y} = chart.getDatasetMeta(datasetIndex).data[dataIndex];
            const x0 = x + offsetX, y0 = y + offsetY;
            const ctx = chart.ctx;
            ctx.save();

            ctx.strokeStyle = lineColor;
            draw_arrow(ctx, x0, y0, x, y);
            ctx.font = textFontSize + "px serif";
            ctx.textAlign = "center";
            ctx.textBaseline = "bottom";
            ctx.strokeStyle = textColor;
            const labelWidth = ctx.measureText(text).width;
            ctx.fillStyle = backgroundColor;
            ctx.fillRect(x0 - labelWidth/2 - paddingX, y0, labelWidth + 2 * paddingX, -textFontSize - 2 * paddingY);
            ctx.fillStyle = textColor;
            ctx.fillText(text, x0,  y0 - paddingY);
            ctx.lineWidth = 2;
            ctx.strokeStyle = lineColor;
            ctx.strokeRect(x0 - labelWidth/2 - paddingX, y0, labelWidth + 2 * paddingX, -textFontSize - 2 * paddingY);
            ctx.restore();
        }
    }],
    data: {
        labels: ['Sep-2018','Oct-2018','Nov-2018','Dec-2018','Jan-2019','Feb-2019','Mar-2019','Apr-2019','May-2019','Jun-2019','Jul-2019','Aug-2019','Sep-2019','Oct-2019','Nov-2019','Dec-2019','Jan-2020','Feb-2020','Mar-2020','Apr-2020','May-2020','Jun-2020','Jul-2020','Aug-2020','Sep-2020','Oct-2020','Nov-2020','Dec-2020','Jan-2021','Feb-2021','Mar-2021','Apr-2021','May-2021','Jun-2021','Jul-2021','Aug-2021','Sep-2021','Oct-2021','Nov-2021','Dec-2021','Jan-2022','Feb-2022','Mar-2022','Apr-2022','May-2022','Jun-2022','Jul-2022','Aug-2022','Sep-2022','Oct-2022','Nov-2022','Dec-2022','Jan-2023','Feb-2023','Mar-2023','Apr-2023','May-2023','Jun-2023','Jul-2023','Aug-2023','Sep-2023','Oct-2023','Nov-2023','Dec-2023','Jan-2024'],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: 'Linux',
                lineTension: 0,
                fill: false,
                data: [0.78, 0.72, 0.80, 0.82, 0.82, 0.77, 0.82, 0.81, 0.84, 0.76, 0.79, 0.80, 0.83, 0.83, 0.81, 0.83, 0.90, 0.83, 0.87, 0.89, 0.91, 0.88, 0.86, 0.89, 0.94, 0.90, 0.90, 0.78, 0.91, 0.81, 0.85, 0.85, 0.86, 0.89, 1.00, 1.02, 1.05, 1.13, 1.16, 1.11, 1.06, 1.02, 1.00, 1.14, 1.12, 1.18, 1.23, 1.27, 1.23, 1.28, 1.44, 1.38, 1.38, 1.27, 0.84, 1.32, 1.47, 1.44, 1.96, 1.82, 1.63, 1.39, 1.91, 1.97, 1.95],
                backgroundColor: '#0C7BDC',
                borderColor: '#0C7BDC',
                borderWidth: 1,
                // trendlineLinear: {
                //     style: '#DC267F',
                //     lineStyle: 'dotted',
                //     width: 2
                // }
            }]
    },
    options: {
        legend: {
            display: true
        },
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        pointRadius: function(ctx){
            return ctx.chart.data.labels[ctx.dataIndex] === 'Aug-2019' ? 6 : 3
        },
        scales: {
            y: {
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                },
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Percentage of Steam users'
                }
            }
        },
        tooltips:
            {
                callbacks: {
                    label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                        var value = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
                        var label = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label;
                        return label + ' ' + value + '%';
                    }
                },
            },
        plugins: {
            specialLabel: {
                datasetIndex: 0,
                xValue: 'Aug-2019',
                text: 'Big Event'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<div style="height: 90vh">
    <canvas id="linuxonly" style="background: rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.5)">
    </canvas>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
```

Comment: Fantastic! Now I just need to style it how I want it, and figure out how to add an arrow to the point coming from it :D - thanks

Comment: I don't know about arrows, chartjs-plugin-datalabels doesn't have those. I added for inspiration the way to start the alternative solution I mentioned earlier, of a custom plugin.

Comment: Oh wow I missed that bit, that could work quite nicely, might have to play around with it. Legendary, thanks!